# Using @RepositoryDefinition and JpaSpecificationExecutor methods doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm having a Spring Data repository class like:

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = Book.class, idClass = Long.class)
public interface BookRepository {

    List<Book> findAll();

    List<Book> findByOrderByPublishDateDesc();

    Book findOne(Long id);

    Book save(Book book);

    boolean exists(Long id);

    void delete(Long id);

    Iterable<Book> findAll(Predicate predicate, OrderSpecifier<?>... orders);
}
```

The standard crud methods do work, however the findAll (from JpaSpecificationExecutor) doesn't work.

Do `@RepositoryDefinition` repositories support using the querydsl (or jpa specification) predicate-aware methods?

Answer (score 2):

According the javadoc

> Annotation to demarcate interfaces a repository proxy shall be created for. Annotating an interface with `RepositoryDefinition` will cause the same behaviour as extending `Repository`.

So it only supports the basic set available on `Repository` (at least that is what I deduce from the docs). If you want more you probably have to extend the specific interface next to adding the annotation.

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = Book.class, idClass = Long.class)
public interface BookRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Book> {}
```

Comment: `Repository` itself does *not* contain anything. The methods from e.g. `CrudRepository` do work.
So probably a better question would be if a Repository can use `JpaSpecificationExecutor` and `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` like methods.

Comment: Btw I don't want to extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor/QueryDslPredicateExecutor` itself as I don't want to expose all the methods.