# What's the difference between @Repository and @RepositoryDefinition in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'd want to know the difference between `@Repository` and `@RepositoryDefinition` in Spring. And which would take in effect with `@EnableNeo4jRepositories`?

Comment: You don't need `@Repository` at all in combination with Spring Data interfaces. That's a common misconception. `@Repository` is a meta annotation which you add to implementations of a repository layer, not interfaces (it's basically the same functionality as `@Component`).

Answer (score 7):

I can't answer in regard to Neo4j, but deciding between the two Spring annotations is a design decision. I'll quote from the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning):

> Typically, your repository interface will extend `Repository`, 
>   `CrudRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository`. Alternatively, if you 
>   do not want to extend Spring Data interfaces, you can also annotate your
>   repository interface with `@RepositoryDefinition`.

The [API doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/RepositoryDefinition.html) is even more clear:

> Annotating an interface with `RepositoryDefinition` will cause the same behaviour as extending `Repository`.

You might be interested in [Using @RepositoryDefinition and JpaSpecificationExecutor methods doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026755/using-repositorydefinition-and-jpaspecificationexecutor-methods-doesnt-work) too.

Answer (score 0):

@Repository is an annotation that tells spring to create a Bean, hence, it needs to be put on a Class. It similar to @Service or @RestController but with some peculiarities regarding the Transactional behaviour and exception handling (annotated classes can be chosen for PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor). It can be seen as specialization of @Component

@Repository definition, according to the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/RepositoryDefinition.html)

> Annotation to demarcate interfaces a repository proxy shall be created for. Annotating an interface with RepositoryDefinition will cause the same behaviour as extending Repository.

This means that and interface annotated with RepositoryDefinition will create a proxy to execute the query methods of the interface